# Travel guides that covers the International E-road network?

Tags: europe, driving, road-trips, guidebooks

During the last days I read a lot about the [International E-road network in Europe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_E-road_network). Since I'm a big road trip fan, I really would like to follow more or less one road in the near future. Does anybody know if there exists a travel guide book (like for example Lonely Planet) that covers one of such roads? I would be interested in information about the details concerning the road trip (what visas are necessary, what permits do I need to take my own car into the country, etc.) as well as the sightseeing in the area of the road.

I'm particularly interested in [E58](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E58), [E60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E60), [E75](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E75) and [E40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_route_E40).

For example  I have a [Lonely Planet book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1864502142) at home that covers a trip from Istanbul to Kathmandu. I'm wondering if there is something similar like that that follows a E route.

I found another interesting book called [Great Journeys](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1742205895), but I´m still looking for a E-road network book.

Comment: I don't expect there's a guide book. But there may be something from an auto club or aimed at campers and caravaners. If not just supplement your travel guide with a road atlas you can buy anywhere. I bought mine at a petrol station on the edge of Berlin.

Comment: Great question btw, inspired in me a lot of ideas for future trips ;)

Comment: Yes there are some nice ideas ;)

Comment: I added a bounty to this question to get more attention. The current answer is not bad, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: In the UK the "E" numbers are never on sign posts or normal maps.   In most of the UK the "E" numbers are often not signed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The belgian tv production company [Woestijnvis](http://www.woestijnvis.be/), has a daily "news show" called [Man bijt hond (Man bites dog)](http://www.een.be/programmas/man-bijt-hond/). In this daily show they have odd items.

Last year they followed two guys who drove from Calais 8500 km to the end of the E40. A brief search on google, didn't show the existence of a DVD of this road doco. Maybe you could write them and ask if they have the series available.

Comment: Clearly different from http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103905/ ;)